# Java RMI timeout in callback

Tags: java, callback, rmi

We are using Java RMI for communication. An RMI client passes a processing request and an object with a callback method to an RMI server. The server invokes the callback when it is done with processing. The setup is similar to the one described in [RMI Callbacks](http://www.ryerson.ca/~dgrimsha/courses/cps841/RMICallbacks.html).

Occasionally we are getting a "read time out" exception in the server upon invoking the callback method. The callback thread stalls for about a minute before the exception is raised.

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: error during JRMP connection establishment; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:286)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at $Proxy2.finished(Unknown Source)
    at com.unrisk.db.grid.GridTask.invokeCallback(com.unrisk.db.grid.GridTask:1292)
    at com.unrisk.db.grid.GridTask.invokeCallbacks(com.unrisk.db.grid.GridTask:1304)
    at com.unrisk.db.service.tasks.EquityMDTask.afterRun(com.unrisk.db.service.tasks.EquityMDTask:276)
    at com.unrisk.db.grid.GridTask.run(com.unrisk.db.grid.GridTask:720)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:228)
    ... 12 more
```

We are using Sun Java JDK 1.6.0_18 under Windows Server 2003 32-bit.

Is it possible to work around the connection problems by tuning RMI related system properties?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the timeouts are described in this bookmark-worthy post:
  http://archives.java.sun.com/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind0208&L=jini-users&P=R27617

In my (limited) experience with JRMP, I found I had to use JVM-global properties to tweak the read timeouts...

digression:
My team now uses Jeri (Java extensible remote invocation) exclusively, which is part of the Apache River (formerly: Sun Jini) project.  Jeri is a lot more configurable than JRMP, allowing you to define your own underlying protocols.